# python parse file

Tags: python, file, parsing, io, save

I have a file with username and emails, in this format :

```
pete,pbellyer@gmail.com
```

I want to only keep the email, so i thought about using a regex like this :

```
import re,sys

Mailfile = sys.argv[1]

file = open(Mailfile, "r")

for MAIL in file.readlines():
   tmp = re.split("\n+", MAIL)
   m = re.match( ',(.+)', MAIL)
   m.group(0)
```

But then I don't know how to store the result in a file.
I always get the last email address in the new file.

What would be the best way to store the results in a file ?
Thanks!

Comment: Is `IP` supposed to be `MAIL`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import sys

infile, outfile = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

with open(infile) as inf, open(outfile,"w") as outf:
    line_words = (line.split(',') for line in inf)
    outf.writelines(words[1].strip() + '\n' for words in line_words if len(words)>1)
```

Comment: And `line.split()` splits on...?

Comment: @Kirk Strauser: yep, fixed that.

Comment: Why are you stripping `words[1]` and then adding `\n` back onto it? Side note: I completely agree with your approach. Just nitpicking for the sake of new users who might be wondering about these things. :-)

Comment: @Kirk Strauser: um... general paranoia? If he had any extraneous whitespace in his original file, now he won't.

Comment: +1, but I would add `(line.split(',') for line in inf if ',' in line)` to avoid the error on blank lines for the non existing subscription on `words[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module (since your data looks comma-separated, at least in your example):

```
import sys
import csv
with open('mail_addresses.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')):
        outfile.write("%s\n" % row[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import sys

Mailfile = sys.argv[1]
Outfile = sys.argv[2]

try:
    in_file = open(Mailfile, 'r')
    out_file = open(Outfile, 'a')

    for mail in in_file.readlines():
        address = mail.split(',')[1].strip()
        out_file.write(address+',') #if you want to use commas to seperate the files, else use something like \n to write a new line.
finally:
    in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
```

Comment: 1) `address` would be a list of values after the split, and 2) `file.readlines` retains the `\n` at the end of each line.

Comment: hum the code echo a : TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list on the address line

Comment: Hum, I was looking for this type of output in the file:

pbellyer@gmail.com\n
pbellyer@gmail.com\n
pbellyer@gmail.com\n

I don't need the coma !